# Gnuplot columnstacked histogram with errorbars

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, errorbar

Suppose I have the following data file, `so-qn.dat`:

```
Type   on on-err off off-err
good   75 5      55  4
bad    15 2      30  3
#other 10 1      15  2
```

which contains values on columns 2 and 4 and corresponding error deltas on columns 3 and 5.

I can produce a columnstacked histogram:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set terminal png
set output 'so-qn.png'
set linetype 1 lc rgb "blue" lw 2 pt 0
set linetype 2 lc rgb "dark-red" lw 2 pt 0
set style data histograms
set style histogram columnstacked
set style fill solid
set ylabel "% of all items"
set yrange [0:100]
set boxwidth 0.75
set xtics scale 0
set xlabel "Option"
plot 'so-qn.dat' using 2 ti col, \
              '' using 4:key(1) ti col
```

[image]

But I can’t figure out how to add errorbars to this. The closest I got so far is with

```
plot 'so-qn.dat' using 2 ti col, '' using 2:3 with yerrorbars lc rgb 'black' ti col, \
              '' using 4:key(1) ti col, '' using 4:5:key(1) with yerrorbars lc rgb 'black' ti col
```

which produces

[image]

but only one of the error bars is in the right spot (I actually have no idea where the bottom left one gets its y from), one is completely invisible (hidden behind the right stack?), and I’d like the error bars to not show up in the key.

Is it possible to combine column-stacked histograms and error bars?

Comment: Actually, after looking at the key, I understand where the bottom left error bar is coming from – that’s the first one for `off-err` (55±4). Looks like the error bars move left-to-right, each restarting with at the first stack, instead of moving along the right stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add errorbars to column-stacked histograms by manually adding plot-commands for the errorbars. To do so, you need, however, to keep track of the y-positions.

Therefore, let's introduce two variables which store the y-position for each of the two columns' errorbars.

```
y1 = -2
y2 = -4
```

You need to initialize these variables with `-(number of column)`
Next, let us define two functions that update the variables `y1, y2`.

```
f1(x) = (y1 = y1+x)
f2(x) = (y2 = y2+x)
```

Now, generate the desired plot via

```
plot 'so-qn.dat' using 2 ti col, \
              '' using 4:key(1) ti col, \
              '' using (0):(f1($2)):3 w yerr t "", \
              '' using (1):(f2($4)):5 w yerr t ""
```

[image]

As you can see, you can supress the errorbars in the key by assigning an empty title (`t ""`). This approach even gives you more flexibility in customizing the appearance of the errorbars (e.g., assign different linestyles etc.).

This being said, I personally think this visualization is rather confusing. You might want to consider another visualization:

```
set bars fullwidth 0
set style data histograms
set style fill solid 1 border lt -1
set style histogram errorbars gap 2 lw 2
plot 'so-qn.dat' using 2:3:xtic(1) ti columnhead(2), \
    '' using 4:5:xtic(1) ti columnhead(4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, this answer comes too late for me personally, since I already handed in the work where I needed the plots, but hopefully it will be useful to someone else, or myself in the future.

Regarding your comment that the visualization is confusing: in my dataset, “good”, “bad” and “other” are percentages. “Other” is commented out because it adds no information – with “other”, all stack would reach exactly 100%. I think that because these percentages belong together, it makes sense to represent each group as a single stack.